# Check database every minute and then send notification

Tags: php, mysql, apache, email, cron

So I have a .php script where it checks the database for a date/time and if that date and time is within the next 30 min, then it will send them an email notification.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(“SELECT user_id FROM meetings WHERE date_and_time = :date_and_time”);
...
sendEmailReminder($userId);
```

I’m running a cron job of this script every minute to make sure the email reminders are being sent out for people who have a meeting within the next 30 min. But I feel like this is using a lot of server resources because I have to run this every minute. What do the “big” sites use to check and send reminders out?

There must be a better way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: Why not try setting the cron to say 30 - 15 mins. instead? TBH, I don't know how the big companies do it, but they most likely have some heavy duty servers working 24/7 and have the resources to do so.

Comment: why to run this script every minute if you want to send to the next 30 min? select all the next 30 mins

Comment: Before you start working on optimizing  the process. Did you check if a. Your select statement b. The send email logic/code is consuming the time/resources of your server? Once you know which of the two is taking more time/resources, we can try to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a large amount of data you have to use one of the queueing systems like
**beanstalkd**
https://beanstalkd.github.io/

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/php-beanstalk/latest/php-beanstalk.pdf

**redis**

https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush

once you get a new meeting insert a new job into the queue with a delay to the time that you want to send the reminder and keep a consumer listening to the queue for ready to pick jobs

Comment: This is what I needed! What do the "big" sites like facebook or google use? What's the best solution of easy scalability?

Comment: I think the best solution for this is redis as it supports clustering if you want to use beanstalkd you can use multiple tube and multiple server

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create an PHP file with your SQL query like what you have now, compare the date_and_time you have in table and compare with current date_and_time using IF/ELSE.

But before, you should SELECT ALL date_and_time from this table to compare with the current date and time +30 minutes (because if i understand, it should be sent 30 min before).

Then if true, execute this script

`$stmt = $dbh->prepare(“SELECT user_id FROM meetings WHERE date_and_time = :date_and_time”);`

ELSE, do nothing.

Execute this script each minute with CRON.